# MS Access SQL add non aggregate field to aggregate

Tags: sql, ms-access, aggregate-functions

I have the following table:

```
tableX

+----+----+----+
| f1 | f2 | f3 |
+----+----+----+
|  1 | a  | 12 |
|  2 | a  | 54 |
|  3 | b  | 23 |
|  4 | b  | 18 |
|  5 | b  | 75 |
+----+----+----+
```

I'd like to reduce the table based on the highest value in f3 with respect to f2 such that we get:

```
+----+----+----+
| f1 | f2 | f3 |
+----+----+----+
|  2 | a  | 54 |
|  5 | b  | 75 |
+----+----+----+
```

I can reduce f2 and f3 by using:

```
SELECT f2, Max(f3)
FROM tableX
GROUP BY f2;
```

I think one solution is close to the below (using aliases and a self join) but I'm struggling a bit trying to get it to work - Access complains that f1 is not part of the aggregate.

```
SELECT a.f1,a.f2, Max(a.f3)
FROM tableX t1
Inner Join tableX t2
On t1.f1 = t2.f1 
GROUP BY t1.f2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track.

Here is what I came up with:

```
select x.f1, x.f2, x.f3
from tablex x
join (
select f2, max(f3) as f3
from tableX
group by f2
  ) j on j.f2 = x.f2 and j.f3 = x.f3
```

I did a little SQL Fiddle for it.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7d4ac4/3

It does not target ms-access, but it should work.

Comment: Many thanks for this. I changed "max(f3) as f3" to "max(f3) as joinf3" to avoid Access circular reference pop-up, and "j.f3 = x.f3" to "j.joinf3 = x.f3" to finish off. I like SQL Fiddle - not seen that site before, will look into it.